# How can I show a tooltip in Angular template (.html) only if a button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, tooltip

this is my button:

```
 <div class="top-left">
      <button [disabled]="receiptItems?.length>0" type="button" data-tooltip="tooltip"  title="Show tooltip!" class="btn xbutton-square" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
```

So in case it is disabled I would like to show a tooltip so user can see why it's disabled. I'm wondering how can I achieve this?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use   `[attr.title]` and then use `if` `else` like you use in `[disabled]`

```
  <button [disabled]="receiptItems?.length>0"  [attr.title]="receiptItems?.length>0 ? 'Show tooltip!' : ''">...</button>
```

**Edit!**

use `[title]` instead of `[attr.title]` is also work !

Comment: tell for more help

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes [title] is also working even better than [attr.title]

Comment: @Roxy'Pro it the same but shortly

Comment: @לבנימלכה Its not behaving same, when I move cursor on disabled button with attr.title message dissapear, and with title it's appearing again and again while moving over button

Comment: hoo I did not know that by the way if it works i really happy to help you

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Thanks, you can check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/51188911/5043867

Comment: @Roxy'Pro anyways `attr.title` and `title` both are same, when you bind with `attr` it just mean you telling angular to bind the attribute explicitly to your element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same conditon of disable for `title` like this -

```
[title]="!receiptItems?.length ? 'my tooltip!' : ''"
```

on button Like this -

```
  <button [disabled]="receiptItems?.length>0"  [title]="!receiptItems?.length ? 'my tooltip!' : ''">...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="top-left" *ngIf="receiptItems?.length>0">
      <button disabled  type="button" data-tooltip="tooltip"  title="Show tooltip!" class="btn xbutton-square" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw" title="Show tooltip!"></i></button>
    </div>

 <div class="top-left" *ngIf="receiptItems?.length <= 0">
      <button type="button" data-tooltip="tooltip"  title="Show tooltip!" class="btn xbutton-square" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
```